# How to use PDFView and PDFThumbnailView in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf, pdfview

I found a PDFView and PDFThumbnailView in Object Library like this pic:

[image]

But my question is how to use it ??? I can't drag it in xib , and no idea to create a PDFView by code .

Any answer or tutorial will be help.

Comment: sometimes this object shows, but sometimes I can't find it ,anyone know what's wrong ???

Answer (score 3):

Both `PDFView` and `PDFThumbnailView` are now available on iOS, as of iOS 11. Code like this should get you going:

```
let pdfView = PDFView()
pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(pdfView)

pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

if let document = PDFDocument(url: pathToYourPDFDocument) {
    pdfView.document = document
}
```